# Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Tags: spring, autowired

I am developing a small Java EE Hibernate Spring application and an error appeared:
`Error creating bean with name 'articleControleur': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;`

```
oct. 26, 2011 3:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Grave: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'articleControleur': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.bd.service.ArticleService com.bd.controleur.ArticleControleur.articleService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.bd.service.ArticleService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4350)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.bd.service.ArticleService com.bd.controleur.ArticleControleur.articleService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.bd.service.ArticleService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.bd.service.ArticleService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
... 35 more

oct. 26, 2011 3:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
Grave: La servlet /ExempleAchref a généré une exception "load()"
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.bd.service.ArticleService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4350)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

And here is my controller ArticleControleur which contains a function for recovering the lists of articles:

```
package com.bd.controleur;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.bd.service.ArticleService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Article/GererArticle")
public class ArticleControleur {

    @Autowired
    ArticleService articleService;

    public ModelAndView listarticle() {

    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("articles", articleService.getAllArticles());

    // new ModelAndView("nom de la page jsp", model qui contient l'ensemble
    // des beans que tu vas passer a cette page)
    return new ModelAndView("GererArticle", model);

    }

}
```

And here is my articleService:

```
package com.bd.service;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.bd.dao.ArticleDao;
import com.bd.entity.Article;

@Service
public class ArticleServiceImp implements ArticleService {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleDao articledao;



    @Override
    public Article getArticleById(int articleId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return articledao.getById(articleId);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveArticle(Article article) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        articledao.save(article);

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteArticle(Article article) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        articledao.delete(article);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Article> getAllArticles() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return articledao.getAll();
    }

}
```

And here is my application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  - Application context containing authentication, channel
  - security and web URI beans.
  -
  - Only used by "filter" artifact.
  -
  -->

<b:beans xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"



    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      ">


  <!-- Auto-detect components -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.bd.entity"/>


</b:beans>
```

Comment: How are you setting up autowiring in your application context? Can you please post the relevant part of your `applicationContext.xml`?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The error shows that `com.bd.service.ArticleService` is not a registered bean. Add the packages in which you have beans that will be autowired in your application context:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bd.service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bd.controleur"/>
```

Alternatively, if you want to include all subpackages in `com.bd`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bd">
     <context:include-filter type="aspectj" expression="com.bd.*" />
</context:component-scan>
```

As a side note, if you're using Spring 3.1 or later, you can take advantage of the [`@ComponentScan`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) annotation, so that you don't have to use any xml configuration regarding component-scan. Use it in conjunction with [`@Configuration`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html).

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Article/GererArticle")
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.bd.service") // No need to include component-scan in xml
public class ArticleControleur {

    @Autowired
    ArticleService articleService;
    ...
}
```

You might find this Spring in depth section on [Autowiring](https://web.archive.org/web/20111120115551/http://springindepth.com/book/in-depth-ioc-autowiring.html) useful.

Comment: In what file this lines should be added ?

Comment: @Oleg in your applicationContext.xml. Make sure the namespace definition for the `context` prefix is included as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16673644/851811)

Comment: I have Maven project and haven't applicationContext.xml.

Comment: I solved it, I have moved my Application class with main method to above package, so autowired doesn't work with classes in sibling packages, only for child packages of current.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a bean declared in your context file that has an id of "articleService"? I believe that autowiring matches the id of a bean in your context files with the variable name that you are attempting to Autowire.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Organization {

    @Id
    @Column(name="org_id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="org_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="org_office_address1")
    private String address1;

    @Column(name="org_office_addres2")
    private String address2;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name="country")
    private String country;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="pkg_id")
    private int pkgId;

    public int getPkgId() {
        return pkgId;
    }

    public void setPkgId(int pkgId) {
        this.pkgId = pkgId;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Column(name="pincode")
    private String pincode;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organization", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<OrganizationBranch> organizationBranch = new HashSet<OrganizationBranch>(0);

    @Column(name="status")
    private String status = "ACTIVE";

    @Column(name="project_id")
    private int redmineProjectId;

    public int getRedmineProjectId() {
        return redmineProjectId;
    }

    public void setRedmineProjectId(int redmineProjectId) {
        this.redmineProjectId = redmineProjectId;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Set<OrganizationBranch> getOrganizationBranch() {
        return organizationBranch;
    }

    public void setOrganizationBranch(Set<OrganizationBranch> organizationBranch) {
        this.organizationBranch = organizationBranch;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress1() {
        return address1;
    }

    public void setAddress1(String address1) {
        this.address1 = address1;
    }

    public String getAddress2() {
        return address2;
    }

    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }

    public void setPincode(String pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }
}
```

You change the private int pkgId line in change datatype int to primitive class name or add annotation @autowired

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to your controller

import static org.aspectj.weaver.tools.cache.SimpleCacheFactory.path;

Here I m trying to upload an image to the database.
[image]and in your controller, you have to remove/disable the @Value annotation please find the screenshot.

How I resolved the issue

Comment: Please add code examples inline, instead of using screenshots.