# Unable to autowire field when unit testing

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa

i tried to use Spring Data jpa with generics but the same exception is handled when i run unit test. 
here is the exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tn.moussi.PostRepositorytest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: tn.moussi.repositories.PostRepository tn.moussi.PostRepositorytest.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: T is not mapped [select t from T t where t.title = :TITLE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:313)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: tn.moussi.repositories.PostRepository tn.moussi.PostRepositorytest.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: T is not mapped [select t from T t where t.title = :TITLE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: T is not mapped [select t from T t where t.title = :TITLE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:876)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: T is not mapped [select t from T t where t.title = :TITLE]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1364)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.fromQueryAnnotation(SimpleJpaQuery.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:280)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:148)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:41)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: T is not mapped [select t from T t where t.title = :TITLE]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3291)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1735)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
    ... 58 more
```

and this is the java code :

import java.io.Serializable;

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;


public interface GenericRepository<T,ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

    @Query("select t from T t where t.title = :TITLE")
    T findByTitle(@Param("TITLE") String title);

}

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import tn.moussi.entities.Post;

@Repository("postRepository")
public interface PostRepository extends GenericRepository< Post, Integer> {


}
```

the unit test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:META-INF/application-context.xml")
public class PostRepositorytest {


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="postRepository")
    PostRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Post post = new Post();
        post.setPostDate(new Date());
        post.setTitle("first post");

        repository.save(post);

        Post dbpost = repository.findByTitle(post.getTitle());
        assertNotNull(dbpost);
        System.out.println(dbpost.getTitle());

    }

}
```

the Entity Class Post :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="POST")
public class Post{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="POST_ID")
    Integer postId;

    @Column(name="TITLE")
    String title;
    @Column(name="POST_DATE")
    Date postDate;

    public Integer getPostId() {
        return postId;
    }
    public void setPostId(Integer postId) {
        this.postId = postId;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public Date getPostDate() {
        return postDate;
    }
    public void setPostDate(Date postDate) {
        this.postDate = postDate;
    }
}
```

The application-context file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<!-- database -->
<jdbc:embedded-database id="datasource" type="H2"></jdbc:embedded-database>

<!--  Entity manager -->
 <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="moussi-tutorial"/>
 </bean>

 <!--  Transaction Manager -->
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
  </bean>

 <!--  Jap repositories -->
 <jpa:repositories base-package="tn.moussi"></jpa:repositories>

<context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="tn.moussi" />

</beans>
```

the persistence.xml file :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">

  <persistence-unit name="moussi-tutorial" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
     <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914363/injection-of-autowired-dependencies-failed   Try adding this to your unitTest @ComponentScan("tn.moussi") if using Spring 3.1 or later

Comment: Are you working from a tutorial? I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: no i'm runing this in an existing project not from a tutorial

Comment: i added @ComponentScan("tn.moussi") and the same exception

Comment: I propose to rephrase and rewrite the question to reflect what the actual problem is. It's about inheriting common finder methods, not about autowiring of repositories.

Comment: the generic method is used several times more than 15, i want to develop it only one time and use the generics to customise the entity class. can u help me please to make this with spring data jpa

Comment: @OliverGierke help please

Comment: No need to poke at people. That won't affect the chance to get an answer. I've already answered. That's it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work as you expect it to. While the concrete classes inherit the method and allow us to find out about the concrete return type at runtime we don't (can't) do any generics replacements for queries manually defined. The reason for that that there's essentially no way to find out about whether you actually refer to the generic type from within the query (read: the T in your query could essentially mean anything, just from looking at the query).

The option you have is to introduce dedicated named queries for each concrete types of T such as `TypeA.findByTitle`, `TypeB.findByTitle` and so on. We'd then use these to back the method inherited into concrete repository interfaces. Also, you might want to annotate the `GenericRepository` interface with @NoRepositoryBean to prevent it from being picked up during component scanning. Read up on the details about that in the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, even thought I'm not the original poster.  You mention the concrete return type can be determined at runtime, is that due inheritance? Which would allow you to use reflection like: `(ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];`

Comment: Thank u Oliver for the explanation,i will remove the @query annotation  and i will follow the reference documentation to resolv the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible.  The problem is that the generic parameter `T` will be different for every interface.  In your `@Query` T is statically defined in the value element on the annotation, `select t from T...`.  In a normal JPA query the type of entity would be specified in the query.  Like follows:

```
@Query("select t from Book t where t.title = :TITLE")
Book findByTitle(@Param("TITLE") String title);
```

If extending interfaces were allowed, Spring Data would need to be smart enough to determine the type of the generic parameter `T` at runtime (which is against the grain with generics, since most operations are compile time).  It would then need to substitute this type into the statically defined query in the `@Query` annotation's value element.  I have not seen any evidence that this is possible.

Comment: the generic method is used multiple times in multiple interfaces.
I want to optimize the development not to repeat the method several times.
is that there is a slution in this direction?

Comment: @user2194541 I can't say for sure, but I don't think there is a solution or at least one using your approach.  I tweeted this at Oliver Geirke (Spring), maybe we will get some input.

Answer (score 0):

I may guess this happens because your JPA provider is not able to process the query in your GenericRepository interface:

```
select t from T t where t.title = :TITLE
```

In order to understand whether this is a root cause or not - try to introduce another findByTitle2 method in your PostRepository that addresses the explicitly named entity:

```
@Query("select t from Post t where t.title = :TITLE")
T findByTitle(@Param("TITLE") String title);
```

Note, that your stacktrace addresses this with the following report:

```
QuerySyntaxException: T is not mapped [select t from T t where t.title = :TITLE]
```

I'm not sure whether such a query parameterization `select t from T t where t.title = :TITLE` is possible at all - because of specifics of generics implementation in java it is not always possible to extract correct parameterized type information in runtime to decide what type is used in certain point of your application.

Comment: i added @Query("select t from Post t where t.title = :TITLE")
T findByTitle(@Param("TITLE") String title); to my PostRepository and it works. which provider should i use to detect generics ??

Comment: because the generic method is used several times more than 15, i want to develop it only one time

Comment: You may want to do it without spring-data-jpa by using JPA Criteria API which is perfectly suited for tasks that require building a complicated query.