# Activiti-Rest with spring boot

Tags: rest, spring-boot, activiti

**This is my pom file**

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.activiti.examples</groupId>
  <artifactId>activiti-examples</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>BPMN 2.0 with Activiti - Examples</name>
  <properties>
    <activiti-version>5.20.0</activiti-version>
  </properties>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
      <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${activiti-version}</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
      <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
      <artifactId>activiti-spring</artifactId>
      <version>${activiti-version}</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
   <!--  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.168</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
    <version>5.17.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency> -->
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter -->
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency> -->
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
          <classpathContainers>
            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/Activiti Designer Extensions</classpathContainer>
          </classpathContainers>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Hi all i am trying to do activiti rest with spring boot.
But i am getting error.
However i am able to build one app for startup.It works fine.But getting error
only in that.Please help to resolve my error.
 You can find the errors below in the snippet.

**These are my errors**

```html
2016-07-28 12:21:56.611  INFO 7112 --- [           main] c.b.a.rest.leaveRequest.MyApplication    : Starting MyApplication on mdnoorshid with PID 7112 (started by noorshid in /media/noorshid/New Volume/BizRuntime/Activiti_Workspace/Activiti-Rest-Complete-Process-LeaveRequest)
2016-07-28 12:21:56.618  INFO 7112 --- [           main] c.b.a.rest.leaveRequest.MyApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-07-28 12:21:57.229  INFO 7112 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@75225d4a: startup date [Thu Jul 28 12:21:57 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-07-28 12:21:59.347  INFO 7112 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66951570] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-07-28 12:22:00.122  INFO 7112 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-07-28 12:22:00.150  INFO 7112 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-07-28 12:22:00.152  INFO 7112 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
2016-07-28 12:22:00.342  INFO 7112 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-07-28 12:22:00.342  INFO 7112 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3119 ms
2016-07-28 12:22:00.910  INFO 7112 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-07-28 12:22:00.919  INFO 7112 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-28 12:22:00.920  INFO 7112 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-28 12:22:00.920  INFO 7112 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-28 12:22:00.921  INFO 7112 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-28 12:22:01.001  WARN 7112 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myRestController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bizruntime.activiti.rest.leaveRequest.MyService com.bizruntime.activiti.rest.leaveRequest.MyRestController.myService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bizruntime.activiti.rest.leaveRequest.MyService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2016-07-28 12:22:01.006  INFO 7112 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-07-28 12:22:01.024 ERROR 7112 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myRestController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bizruntime.activiti.rest.leaveRequest.MyService com.bizruntime.activiti.rest.leaveRequest.MyRestController.myService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bizruntime.activiti.rest.leaveRequest.MyService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
 at com.bizruntime.activiti.rest.leaveRequest.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bizruntime.activiti.rest.leaveRequest.MyService com.bizruntime.activiti.rest.leaveRequest.MyRestController.myService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bizruntime.activiti.rest.leaveRequest.MyService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bizruntime.activiti.rest.leaveRequest.MyService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 ... 19 common frames omitted

2016-07-28 12:22:01.028  INFO 7112 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/media/noorshid/New%20Volume/BizRuntime/Activiti_Workspace/Activiti-Rest-Complete-Process-LeaveRequest/target/classes/, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/activiti/activiti-engine/5.20.0/activiti-engine-5.20.0.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/activiti/activiti-bpmn-converter/5.20.0/activiti-bpmn-converter-5.20.0.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/activiti/activiti-bpmn-model/5.20.0/activiti-bpmn-model-5.20.0.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/activiti/activiti-process-validation/5.20.0/activiti-process-validation-5.20.0.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/activiti/activiti-image-generator/5.20.0/activiti-image-generator-5.20.0.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-email/1.4/commons-email-1.4.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.5.5/javax.mail-1.5.5.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/mybatis/mybatis/3.3.0/mybatis-3.3.0.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.8.2/joda-time-2.8.2.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.21/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.3/groovy-all-2.4.3.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.21/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.21/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.33.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.33.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.6/jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.6/jackson-annotations-2.6.6.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.6/jackson-core-2.6.6.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/activiti/spring-boot-starter-basic/5.17.0/spring-boot-starter-basic-5.17.0.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/activiti/activiti-spring/5.17.0/activiti-spring-5.17.0.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.6/commons-pool-1.6.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.33/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.33.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.33/tomcat-juli-8.0.33.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/noorshid/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar]
```

**My Main Class**

```html
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.bizruntime.activiti.rest.util.Config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyApplication 
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
}

//changing default database to mysql
public DataSource database(){
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().url(Config.getConfig().getProperty("url"))
            .username(Config.getConfig().getProperty("username")).password(Config.getConfig().getProperty("password"))
            .driverClassName(Config.getConfig().getProperty("driverClassName")).build();
}
}
```

**My Rest Class**

```html
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.activiti.engine.task.Task;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class MyRestController
{
@Autowired
private MyService myService; 

@RequestMapping(value="/process", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void startProcessInstance(){
 myService.startProcess();
}

@RequestMapping(value="/tasks", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<TaskRepresentation> getTasks(@RequestParam String assignee) {
    List<Task> tasks = myService.getTasks(assignee);
    List<TaskRepresentation> dtos = new ArrayList<TaskRepresentation>();
    for (Task task : tasks) {
        dtos.add(new TaskRepresentation(task.getId(), task.getName()));
    }
    return dtos;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/claim",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void claimTheTask(String taskId,String assignee){
 myService.claimTask(taskId, assignee); 
}

@RequestMapping(value="/complete",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void completeTheTask(String taskId){
 myService.completeTask(taskId);
}

static class TaskRepresentation
{
String id;
String name;
public TaskRepresentation(String id,String name){
 this.id=id;
 this.name=name;
}
public String getId() {
 return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
 this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
 return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
 this.name = name;
}
}
}
```

**My Service Class**

```html
import org.activiti.engine.RuntimeService;
import org.activiti.engine.TaskService;
import org.activiti.engine.task.Task;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.bizruntime.activiti.rest.util.Config;

public class MyService {

 @Autowired
 private RuntimeService runtimeService;

 @Autowired
 private TaskService taskService;

 @Transactional
 public void startProcess() {
  Map<String, Object> variables1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  variables1.put("name", Config.getConfig().getProperty("name"));
  variables1.put("noOfLeaveDays1", Config.getConfig().getProperty("noOfLeaveDays"));
  variables1.put("emailId", Config.getConfig().getProperty("emailId"));
  variables1.put("reason", Config.getConfig().getProperty("reason"));
  runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("restLeaveRequest", variables1);
 }
 
 @Transactional
 public List<Task>getTasks(String asignee){
 return taskService.createTaskQuery().taskAssignee(asignee).list();
 }
 
 @Transactional
 public void claimTask(String taskId,String assignee){
  taskService.claim(taskId,assignee);
 }
 
 @Transactional
 public void completeTask(String taskId){
  Map<String,Object>variables2=new HashMap<String, Object>();
  variables2.put("approveRequest1",Config.getConfig().getProperty("approveRequest"));
  variables2.put("remarks1",Config.getConfig().getProperty("remarks"));
  taskService.complete(taskId,variables2);
 }
 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Injection of autowired dependencies failed;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914363/injection-of-autowired-dependencies-failed)

Comment: always search first for exception name and message.

Comment: @dit Yup can you identify where is the actual error

Answer (score 1):

Your MyService class needs to have the @Component or @Service annotation to be picked up by Spring component scanning.

Also, make sure the class is in an autoscanned package.

Comment: Hi Joram thanks for your attention i did exactly what you said but error is same.I am not using xml bean file,can you say how to bring class in  autoscannned package.

Comment: MySerivce class has already has @service annotation but still getting problem.Please help me how to resolve that one

Answer (score 0):

Add @Service or @Component annotation to your MyService class. so, that it can be initialized before being injected.

Comment: Srry abbas Same error only i did like that '@Service'
'@Component'
public class MyService {  Plz igonre single quote.Thanks for your attention

Comment: `@ComponentScan` will by default scan in the package of the class it is called in. see - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

you can either transfer your classes into the package of your main class. or provide a value to your component scan annotation.

Comment: hi abbas i did the same, i have mentioned the specific package in '@'componentScan("my main package").And also i have added '@'component in my both class MyRestController and MyService class.But error is same 'Error creating bean with name 'myRestController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;'

Comment: However i did one simple project where i have mentioned only one package,its working fine but getting problem in my second project where i have given two packages.

Comment: for multiple packages, try something like this - `@ComponentScan({"your.package.first","your.package.second"})`

Comment: oops again getting the same error.I don't getting why it is coming.I have added '@'component annotation.But still getting the same error.Error is again like that for **my rest class**  **'Error creating bean with name 'myRestController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;'.**

Comment: lets try one last time! remove all of your `@Annotations` from your `MyApplication` class and use `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"your.package.first","your.package.second"})`. last trick in my pocket ;)

Comment: ha ha ha okay abbas lets try it

Comment: oops (: nooooooooooo.Anyway thanks abbas for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

In your class MyApplication, enable component scanning as below.

You should include the packages for **your services,controllers, etc.**

```
@ComponentScan({
      "com.abc.xyz.package1"
    , "com.abc.xyz.package2"
    })
```

As suggested by most people here, add @Service into your MyService Class ( I cannot see that annotation in this question, you may **not updated** this question).

Comment: Thanks sundaraja for your response.Sorry i have not updated my question but i did already what you are suggesting to me.But still getting the same error only.

Comment: Just to verify, did you added @Service too? please post your pom.xml too.

Comment: yep i have added.Okay i am posting pom.xml also