# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I am creating spring mvc project in eclipse along with using hibernate having following details:

**Error**

```
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springRestController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.ipl.services.UserScoreService com.ipl.controller.SpringRestController.userScoreService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userScoreServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDao com.ipl.services.UserScoreServiceImpl.userScoreDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userScoreDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.ipl.model.UserScore
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.ipl.services.UserScoreService com.ipl.controller.SpringRestController.userScoreService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userScoreServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDao com.ipl.services.UserScoreServiceImpl.userScoreDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userScoreDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.ipl.model.UserScore
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userScoreServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDao com.ipl.services.UserScoreServiceImpl.userScoreDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userScoreDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.ipl.model.UserScore
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDao com.ipl.services.UserScoreServiceImpl.userScoreDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userScoreDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.ipl.model.UserScore
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userScoreDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.ipl.model.UserScore
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.ipl.model.UserScore
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.ipl.model.UserScore
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.ipl.model.UserScore
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:775)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 64 more



**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.ipl" />

 <mvc:annotation-driven />

 <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ipl" />
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="admin" />
 </bean>

  <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
    <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
    </bean>

 <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>com.ipl.model.UserScore</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="txManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <!--<bean id="UserScoreDao" class="com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDaoImpl"></bean>
 <bean id="UserScoreService" class="com.ipl.services.UserScoreServiceImpl"></bean>-->

 <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
  class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

 <bean id="UserScoreDao" class="com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDaoImpl"></bean>
 <bean id="UserScoreService" class="com.ipl.services.UserScoreServiceImpl"></bean>


</beans>




**UserScoreDaoImpl.java**

package com.ipl.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ipl.model.UserScore;

@Component 
public class UserScoreDaoImpl implements UserScoreDao{

    @Autowired
     SessionFactory sessionFactory;

     Session session = null;
     Transaction tx = null;

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     @Override
    public List getEntityList() throws Exception {
         session = sessionFactory.openSession();
          tx = session.beginTransaction();
          List userScoreList = session.createCriteria(UserScore.class)
            .list();
          tx.commit();
          session.close();
          return userScoreList;
    }


}


**UserScoreDao.java**


package com.ipl.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.ipl.model.UserScore;

public interface UserScoreDao {

    public List getEntityList() throws Exception;
}

UserScoreService.java :

package com.ipl.services;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.ipl.model.UserScore;;

public interface UserScoreService { 
     public List getEntityList() throws Exception;

}


**UserScoreServiceImpl.java** 

package com.ipl.services;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDao;
import com.ipl.model.UserScore;

public class UserScoreServiceImpl implements UserScoreService{
    @Autowired

    UserScoreDao userScoreDao;

    @Override
    public List getEntityList() throws Exception {
         return userScoreDao.getEntityList();
    }

}
```

But when i try to run the project i am getting the error "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'RestController'"

Comment: You will get your answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914363/injection-of-autowired-dependencies-failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear:

```
No identifier specified for entity: com.ipl.model.UserScore
```

Without seeing your model it seems you have not specified a field annotated with `@Id` at your `UserScore` entity. Each `@Entity` needs an `@Id`, representing the primary key in the database.

---

You have marked `UserScore` as an annotated class:

```
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
      <value>com.ipl.model.UserScore</value>
     </list>
   </property>
```

And based on this:

```
List userScoreList = session.createCriteria(UserScore.class).list();
```

it is clear you are using `UserScore` to get data from the DB via hibernate, so it does not matter whether it is your view. To hibernate it has to be an Entity. You need to annotate that bean with `@Entity` (easier than use xml configuration) and mark the field matching the primary key with `@Id`.

[Marking a POJO as persistent entity](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-entity)

An example:

[Spring Hibernate Integration](http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-hibernate-session-factory-annotation/)

Comment: But UserScore is my view without primary key

Answer (score 0):

since you have defined a **UserScoreDao** bean in the xml context like this:

```
<bean id="UserScoreDao" class="com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDaoImpl"></bean>
```

At the same time, the UserScoreDaoImpl is annotated with @Component which means there will be another UserScoreDao bean in the application context and the name will be **userScoreDaoImpl**.

As a result, you have two **UserScoreDao** beans in your application context. Spring doesn't know which one it should wire to the ** UserScoreServiceImpl** bean.

Maybe you can try removing the bean declaration in the xml file by comment it:

```
<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
      class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<!--<bean id="UserScoreDao" class="com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDaoImpl"></bean>
 <bean id="UserScoreService" class="com.ipl.services.UserScoreServiceImpl"></bean>
<bean id="UserScoreDao" class="com.ipl.dao.UserScoreDaoImpl"></bean>
<bean id="UserScoreService" class="com.ipl.services.UserScoreServiceImpl"></bean>-->
```